# How retrieve all data stored in In-memory cache via cache-manager

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'am using cache-manager as a in-memory data storage as described in doc https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-manager

Is there any possible way to retrieve all data as a example something like

```
const value = this.cacheManager.getall();
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a `store` property in `cacheManager` from which you can get all `keys` and get the data.

```js
@Get('get-all-data')
async getData() {
  //Get all keys
  const keys = await this.cacheManager.store.keys();

  //Loop through keys and get data
  const allData: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    allData[key] = await this.cacheManager.get(key);
  }
  return allData;
}
```